# Append selected options to drop down / select boxes after .detach - Laravel, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

Happy Monday!

So having found I am unable to use .hide and .show in IE, Edge and safari, I have found myself using .detach to remove filtered drop down options.

The only issue with this is I am unable to get all the options back after using it should I wish to make a different selection in the "SECTOR" select box.

I have tried .append and .prepened but to no avail!

HTML is as follows

```
    <select class="form-control" id="sector">
    <option selected>PLEASE CHOOSE A SECTOR </option>
    <option value="1">COLOUR</option>                   
    <option value="2">VEHICLE</option> 

    <option selected>PLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION...</option>
    <option value="1" data-sector="1">BLACK</option>
    <option value="2" data-sector="1">GREEN</option>
    <option value="3" data-sector="1">BLUE</option>

    <option value="1" data-sector="2">CAR</option>
    <option value="2" data-sector="2">PLANE</option>
    <option value="3" data-sector="2">BUS</option>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
    $("#product option[data-sector!='" + sel + "']").detach();
    $("#product option[data-sector='" + sel + "']").show();
    $("#product").parent().removeClass("hidden");
```

Would love some help and advice on this,

Thanks

Mike

Comment: have you tried replacing the HTML of the select DOM ? using `.html()`

Comment: I did think of that, but there are over 30 products to replace in the DOM with Html and  the string would be quite long if I had to write that into jquery.

Comment: have a function to write the html options from what should be activated. it doesn't differ from the rest of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE!

So Safari does not accept .hide or .show on elements with the options tag. I used N69S Idea of appending the items but rather than using .html I added the options into variables that could be added on change of each drop down and then used a loop.

so instead of:

```
$("#product option[data-sector!='" + sel + "']").detach();
$("#product option[data-sector='" + sel + "']").show();
```

I now use:

```
For (var item of data_products['sector_' + sel]) {
    $("#product").append('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.label </option>');
}
```

Hope this helps others

Thanks

Mike